# some of my query isn't executing

Tags: php, mysqli

I am completely new at programming in php, taking this course on w3schools, I am trying to do the following, the database gets created but table don't and neither does the insertions too.

```
<form action="sql.php" method="post">
  <br> Name: <br>
  <input type="text" name="pName">
  <br> Age: <br>
  <input type="text" name="pAge">
  <br> Position <br>
  <input type="text" name="position">
  <br> Goals: <br>
  <input type="text" name="goals">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['pName'];
    $age = $_POST['pAge'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $goals = $_POST['goals'];
    echo $name . $age . $position . $goals;
    $con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE Arsenal;';
    $sql1 = 'CREATE TABLE Players (Name varchar(225) NOT NULL, Age int(11) NOT NULL, Position varchar(225) NOT NULL, Goals int(11) NOT NULL);';
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO players ( Name, Age, Position, Goals) VALUES ( \$name, \$age, \$position, \$goals )";

    mysqli_select_db($con, 'Arsenal');

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      echo 'success';
    }

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
      echo 'success';
    }

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) {
      echo 'success';
    }
  }
```

Comment: You select the database before it's created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `mysqli_select_db($con, 'Arsenal');` immediately after creating the database, otherwise the sql server doesn't know in which database to create the table.

Try placing it after the first `echo 'success';`

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, in your code, every time the user submit the form your code establish the conexion with mysql, creates a database and creates a table ( wrongly cuz you don't select the database in the conexion so it won't be created ( the table I mean ). You must separate your code, and the only thing you have to execute when the user submit the form is the INSERT sentence. 
So let's see, you can stablish the conexion like you do and then look if the database is created:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'Arsenal'
```

Once you know that the database is created and exists you select it in your conexion:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'Arsenal');
```

But be sure you don't do it while you're connected with the last conexion you created to check the database ( you should finish it or modify the conexion, more at php.net )

So now you're connected to the right database and you're able to create the table, you have to do it just one time, not every time the user submits the form.

Finally when you have your table you're able to do the insertion every time the user submits the form.

Your sentences were good only you have a little misunderstanding about how SQL works.
In addition, that kind of code is vulnerable to SQL Injection ( the user could execute SQL instruction using your form, so they would be able to do whatever they want with the DB or even the computer which owns the DB ) take a look to prepared statements once you get better with the basics of PHP - MYSQL.

I hope this solved your wonder, be free to comment if you have any doubt

Answer (score 0):

The Database name Should be a String, And also there is an unwanted semicolon in the sql, after Arsenal. The following should work.

```
Create a variable $newDB="Arsenal";
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' . $newDB . '';
```